# How do I create an automatic playlist of albums not recently played?

Tags: windows, itunes, playlists

I'd like to create a smart playlist that includes randomly chosen albums from my music library.  Once I listen to the album on my iPod touch, I'd like it to remove that album and substitute a new randomly chosen album when I sync.  Music should play in album order, not song order.

Is there any way to do this, or at least come close?

BTW, I'm on Windows, so a Mac plugin won't help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just create a Smart Playlist with the criteria you outlined:

`Last Played` is not in the last `X days`

or `Plays` is less than `1` (or `2`, or `3`)

Limit it to a time period or size, selected by album.

Make sure Live Update is checked so that the album will update itself as the play counts change, etc.

It should build a playlist that will update accordingly every time you sync your iPod (play counts and last played dates are synced).

I've used similar playlists to make sure high rated, low-play-count songs get added to my iPod for years.  Keeps things from getting stale, especially in a large music collection...

[image: iTunes Random Albums]